# Why does Hopcroft-Karp only work on bipartite graphs?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, bipartite-matching

I have a simple question which I cannot answer, and it relates to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42794263/symmetric-bipartite-matching-of-elements-in-list).

What I cannot answer is this:

1. Why does a graph with bidirectional edges destroy the "bipartiteness" of the graph?
2. Depending on the answer to question 1, why wouldn't Hopcroft-Karp work on bidirectional graphs?

Specifically, for question 1, it seems we can do the following:

1. Assume that a graph with bidirectional edges with node set $A$ with cardinality $|A|$ is actually two sets of nodes $B, C$, each with cardinality equivalent to $|A|$ such that $|B \cup C| = 2 |A|$ and there is guaranteed to be an edge from $B \rightarrow C$ if there is an edge from $C \rightarrow B$.
2. This would be analogous to the stable marriage problem, where every time a marriage is desired in one direction, it is reciprocated. It seems like an unlikely but valid setup.

Is there a problem with viewing a bipartite graph in this way? It seems like a valid setup to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see why bi-directional edges are relevant here (or what problem your construction tries to solve), the question you reference is only about undirected graphs. But I can understand your confusion with that Q&A pair. My understanding is that:

1. The questioner wants to match the entries of an array $A$ to other entries of this array, where the edges are given due to some condition, and try to do so by making a copy $B$ of $A$, and create a bipartite graph on them. However, they note that then they need the additional requirement that if $(A[i],B[j])$, are matched then $(A[j],B[i])$ must also be matched
2. The answer notes that they should not try to make a bipartite graph. What they mean is that the additional constraint on the bipartite graph corresponds to the original edge-relation on the array $A$. As the original edges were arbitrary, we need to perform matching on a general undirected graph.

The standard formulation of the Hopcroft-Karp algorithm uses the fact that the graph is bipartite to ensure finding augmenting paths is not too difficult. It is apparently [possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm#Non-bipartite_graphs) to extend this procedure efficiently for general undirected graphs, but this is rather complicated, so using another algorithm such as Edmonds algorithm seems a better choice.